# Incompatible shapes in keras

Tags: machine-learning, keras, computer-vision, keras-layer

I am trying to use U-net network architeture for stereo vision.
I have datasets with 3 different image sizes (1240x368, 1224x368 and 1384x1104).

Here is My whole class:

```python
import pickle
from keras.models import Sequential  
from keras.layers import Convolution2D, MaxPooling2D, UpSampling2D, Conv2DTranspose
from keras.utils import np_utils
import sys, numpy as np
import keras
import cv2

pkl_file = open('data.p', 'rb')
dict = pickle.load(pkl_file)

X_data = dict['images']
Y_data = dict['disparity']

data_num = len(X_data)
train_num = int(data_num * 0.8)

X_train = X_data[:train_num]
X_test = X_data[train_num:]

Y_train = Y_data[:train_num]
Y_test = Y_data[train_num:]

def gen(X, Y):
    while True:
        for x, y in zip(X, Y):
            yield x, y


model = Sequential()
model.add(Convolution2D(6, (2, 2), input_shape=(None, None, 6), activation='relu', padding='same'))
model.add(Convolution2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(Convolution2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Convolution2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(Convolution2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(Convolution2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Convolution2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(Convolution2D(256, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(Convolution2D(256, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(UpSampling2D(size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Conv2DTranspose(256, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(Conv2DTranspose(256, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(Conv2DTranspose(128, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(UpSampling2D(size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Conv2DTranspose(128, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(Conv2DTranspose(128, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(Conv2DTranspose(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(UpSampling2D(size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Conv2DTranspose(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(Conv2DTranspose(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(Conv2DTranspose(3, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.compile(loss=['mse'], optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit_generator(gen(X_train, Y_train), steps_per_epoch=len(X_train), epochs=5)
scores = model.evaluate(X_test, Y_test, verbose=0)
```

When I try to run this code, I get an error in which it says:

Incompatible shapes: [1,370,1242,3] vs. [1,368,1240,3]
I resized the pictures to be divisible by 8 since I have 3 maxpool layers.
As input I put 2 images (I am doing stereo vision) and as an output I get disparity map for the first image. I am concatenating 2 images by putting the second one in third dimension (np.concatenate((img1,img2), axis=-1).
Can somebody tell me what I am doing wrong?
Here is my trace:

Traceback (most recent call last):

```python
File "C:\Users\Ivan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1322, in _do_call
    return fn(*args)
File "C:\Users\Ivan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1307, in _run_fn
    options, feed_dict, fetch_list, target_list, run_metadata)
File "C:\Users\Ivan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1409, in _call_tf_sessionrun
    run_metadata)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Incompatible shapes: [1,370,1242,3] vs. [1,368,1240,3]
[[Node: loss/conv2d_transpose_9_loss/sub = Sub[T=DT_FLOAT, _class=["loc:@training/Adam/gradients/loss/conv2d_transpose_9_loss/sub_grad/Reshape"], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0"](conv2d_transpose_9/Relu-1-0-TransposeNCHWToNHWC-LayoutOptimizer, _arg_conv2d_transpose_9_target_0_2/_303)]]
[[Node: loss/mul/_521 = _Recv[client_terminated=false, recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0", send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0", send_device_incarnation=1, tensor_name="edge_2266_loss/mul", tensor_type=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"]()]]
```

I tried resizing pictures and learning works, but since as a result I get disparity maps, resizing is not a good option. Does anybody have any advice?

Comment: please post the full error  / traceback, so that it gets clear which layer is responsible for the error

Comment: @blue-phoenox I edited it in question. It's the last transpose conv2d layer

Comment: I think you should use input shape to be same for every image i.e. change `input_shape=(None, None, 6)` to `input_shape=(370,1240, 3)` and resize every image  to 1240x370x3

Comment: @user8190410 I want to avoid that if possible

Comment: you can also select maximum size of image as input shape i.e. max size = 1920x1080x3 and pad the images whose size is less than max size

Comment: @user8190410 I tried what you said, but since as a result I get disparity maps, resizing is not a good option. Does anybody have any advice?

Comment: I think I may have found solution: If the picture is too big to fit in convolutional layer, I can add Cropping layer to crop the image to the size I want it to be. I will try later then, if it works, post it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

If the picture is too big to fit in conv2dTransponse, you can use [Cropping2d](https://keras.io/layers/convolutional/#cropping2d) layer so it crops the picture on wished size. This works if input picture has even number of pixels.